# Как сделать такой код через if?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, который выполняется если значение совпадает с чем-то.

К примеру если `2 + 2 = 4`, то тогда выполняется определенное действие, 
а если `2 + 2 = 5`, то тогда выполняется другое действие и т.д.

Есть код прописанный с такими условиями:

```
if (test) {

  var commands = {
    'совпадает с этим': function() {
      //то тогда выполняется это...
    },
     'hello': function() {
      alert('Hi');
    },
    'Tell *firstName that *text': function(firstName, text){
       alert(firstName + 'I was asked to tell you  that' + text);
    },
};
```

Как можно **правильно** переписать данный код с условным оператором `if`, что бы он корректно работал на JavaScript?

Comment: Я мало что понял, но, похоже, вам нужна конструкция [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: Да что то типо того, но вопрос по сути как сделать код рабочим использую данную конструкцию?

Comment: @arthru Пожалуйста, переформулируйте, вопрос так, чтобы было ясно, что вы хотите. Иначе мы просто (с большой вероятностью) не сможем вам помочь.

Comment: Мне нужна помощь с тем что бы сделать код который я выложил рабочим, это консутркция if, но она не работает, что можо дописать что бы она начала работать?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен на 100% Описание не ясно на 100% И это не потому, что ночь и у меня голова не варит

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать вот так.

```js
var commands = {
  'совподает с этим': function() {
    //то тогда выполняеться это...
  },
   'hello': function() {
    alert('Hi');
  },
  'Tell *firstName that *text': function(firstName, text){
     alert(firstName + 'I was asked to tell you  that' + text);
  }
 };

 document.getElementById('send').onclick = function (e){
  var value = document.getElementById('text').value;
  for (var key in commands) {
    if(value === key){
   commands[value]();
     break;
    }
  }
 };
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="submit" id="send" value="Отправить">
```

Comment: Идеально! только нужно еще что бы то что написанно со звездочкой в начале становилось именно как значение которое пользователь введет. Как в последнем примере. Tell Alex that you are cool, то тогда выдаст нам Alex I was asked to tell you that you are cool